# Looking to purchase better OCR software

Tags: ocr

I’m looking for advice on the best OCR (optical character recognition) software to convert tens of thousands of low-quality scans with. I don’t have access to the originals. I am willing to spend around $200 or more.

I have been using Able2Extract and have experimented with other software. Advertisements on software sites are extremely uninformative. Much OCR software appears to be geared towards high-quality scans and other “bells and whistles” that seem irrelevant to making accurate conversions.

The following are some of the capabilities I’d value in ocr software, none of which I’ve found. The first three would be game changers.

**#1**: Accurately establishing table structures is one of the most important parts of OCR, and errors in setting column breaks is one of the most common ways that OCR fails. It is often the case that you can have the software create table structures before one manually corrects them.

Before this initial step, it would be very useful to be able to tell the software how many columns are in each table, or how many columns are in the tables that appear in different page ranges. This would obviate the need to erase unnecessary column breaks/separators, or add column breaks when correcting table structures manually. One would still often need to move some column breaks, but fewer manual corrections would be needed.

Relatedly, one could tell the software in advance that all the columns in a table are of equal width, or that all the columns save the first column in a table are of equal width.

Existing commercial software does allow one to apply a particular table structure to multiple pages, but there are two problematic aspects with how this is done. The first is that the number of columns in tables on different pages may be the same, but the placement of column breaks is often different on different pages. For example, column break placement is often different on odd versus even-numbered pages. Applying the same table structure to a page range forces the column breaks to always appear in the same place. The user then has to manually specify that the table structure is different within the originally specified range, and then laboriously move the column breaks on different pages. What is suggested here is far better than what already exists.

A second smaller problem is that no quick way to feed in a series of page ranges for the same table structure is provided. Existing software allows one to extend a page range. Existing software allows one to save a table structure with a particular name, and then click on pages and apply a particular saved table structure to that page. These options aren’t as efficient as either 1) making a list of page numbers and feeding it to the software, or 2) specifying odd versus even page number groups.

OCR software is reasonably good at placing column breaks/separators, it just has a habit of putting in too many or missing some.

Manually adding and subtracting column breaks for thousands of pages is extremely time consuming. The options suggested here would save immense amounts of time.

**#2**: Internally, the software is assigning probabilities that a character is a particular character.  When it is unsure what a character is, this should result in a flag that can be checked manually.

Best of all, a grid of probabilities mirroring the two-dimensional data table produced by the OCR would be produced. These would be the probability that the reported character is correct. Once in Excel, this probability could easily be converted into color coding and other flags making it easy to see which cells need to be checked against the original source. A probability below a particular threshold that the user specifies could create these flags.

The software Abbyy FineReader does flag cells it is unsure of, but one has to laboriously go through the doc one cell at a time inside of Abbyy and compare it to the original, which is far less efficient than having a spreadsheet with flags. In the latter case, the flagged cells can be checked against the original in groups. Furthermore, the flags are dichotomous, the user can’t set a threshold via experimentation by comparing to the original source.

It might be the case that private software businesses don’t want to produce matrixes like the ones suggested here. This may allow their products to be reverse engineered, or it may expose them to criticism that results in loss of sales.

**#3**: It should be possible to specify in advance which columns are numeric, and which are a mix of numeric and alpha characters.

It is extremely common for tables to have the first column be a mix of alpha and numeric characters, the top row (i.e., column headers) be such a mix, and everything below and to the right of this area to be nothing but numbers. OCR often results in numerous alpha characters or highly irregular characters for what should only be numbers.

**#4**: Keyboard shortcuts should be available for changing the mode one is in regarding adding or deleting column breaks, or creating or deleting entire tables, instead of having to move the mouse over to the right of the software area to click on the desired mode change.

**#5**: All kinds of highly uncommon irregular characters often result from the OCR process. The option to exclude highly irregular characters (for example, characters that don’t appear anywhere on a keyboard) should be provided.

This option would probably not save that much time if option **#2** is implemented.

**#6**: Being able to specify what font the original is in would be a way to incrementally improve conversion accuracy.

This option is less important than the above options, especially if the above options are implemented.

**#7**: Being able to feed the software a dictionary of common words that might appear in a particular set of tables would improve conversion accuracy. For example, a list of county names could be provided in tables where the first column is a list of counties.

This option is less important than the above options, especially if the above options are implemented.